# Fit a Circle by Least Square Method

Tags: c++, least-squares

Hi I want to find a circle by least square methhod with lots of point I wrote this code, but it isn't work and no error message 
(My code has a function which FittingCircle I think my function (FittingCircle) is wrong But I can't find my error)

Thanks your adanced

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 

#define A(i,j) A[i + j * 3] 
using namespace std; 
bool FittingCircle(double* A, double* B) 
{ 

    double Sum; 
    double Diagonal[3]; 
    Sum= A(0,0); 
    if (Sum <= 0.f) return false; 
    Diagonal[0]= sqrt(Sum); 
    Sum= A(0,1); 
    A(1,0)= Sum / Diagonal[0]; 
    Sum= A(0,2); 
    A(2,0)= Sum / Diagonal[0]; 
    Sum= A(1,1) - A(1,0) * A(1,0); 
    if (Sum <= 0.f) return false; 
    Diagonal[1]= sqrt(Sum); 
    Sum= A(1,2) - A(1,0) * A(2,0); 
    A(2,1)= Sum / Diagonal[1]; 
    Sum= A(2,2) - A(2,1) * A(2,1) - A(2,0) * A(2,0); 
    if (Sum <= 0.f) return false; 
    Diagonal[2]= sqrt(Sum); 
    Sum= B[0]; 
    B[0]= Sum / Diagonal[0]; 
    Sum= B[1] - A(1,0) * B[0]; 
    B[1]= Sum / Diagonal[1]; 
    Sum= B[2] - A(2,1) * B[1] - A(2,0) * B[0]; 
    B[2]= Sum / Diagonal[2]; 
    Sum= B[2]; 
    B[2]= Sum / Diagonal[2]; 
    Sum= B[1] - A(2,1) * B[2]; 
    B[1]= Sum / Diagonal[1]; 
    Sum= B[0] - A(1,0) * B[1] - A(2,0) * B[2]; 
    B[0]= Sum / Diagonal[0]; 
    return true; 
} 
int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    double matris[3]={25,30,50}; 
    double matris2[3]={40,25,50}; 

    FittingCircle(matris,matris2); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange that your code don't crash.

The first argument of `FittingCircle()` is a `double` pointer but is used as a matrix (via `#define A(i,j) A[i + j * 3]`.

So, reading in `A(2,2)`, you read in `A[2 + 2 * 3]`, that is `A[8]`.

But the first argument that you pass to `FittingCircle()` is

```
double matris[3]={25,30,50};
```

When you read in `A[8]`, you read in `matris[8]`.

Very, very dangerous and undefined behaviour.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much Now I am confused What should write in matris instead For example

Comment: I wrote these but I can't get a result  double matris[8]={25,30,50,40,20,71,43,78}; 
    double matris2[8]={40,25,50,42,35,74,53,24}; 
    
    FittingCircle(matris,matris2); 
    return 0;

Comment: @aspodap - I don't know your algorithm, so I don't know what you exactly have to do. But if you read in `A[8]` (that is `matris[8]`), `mastris` **must** be at least of nine position, so `double matris[9] = { /* nine values */ };`. About `matris2`, I see that you read and write in it only in positions 0, 1 and 2. So `double matris2[3] = { /* three valuse */ };` should be enough.

Comment: Hi thanks ı have no error but program doesn't write result(circle equations) just work